# What are the differences between Specialized Targa and Henge?

Tags: saddle

Namely I am interested in such data:

- length
- the width of the nose
- *I couldn't find a picture of Targa from the side* -- is Targa (looking from side) a flat saddle? (Henge is not)
- is the shell flexible or rather rigid (don't confuse with padding) -- *for example I would say Specialized Romin is super rigid*

Probably the only differences I know are the weight, price and overall look. So if you know more important differences, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, today I got both saddles, and I can answer my own question :-)

Those saddles are twins, you know already about the weight difference (Targa is heavier), and the only difference I found which was not in spec is flex of the shell. Henge is very stiff (the shell, not the padding), while Targa is rather flexible.

*And while I am writing this, I rode Henge Test 143, it is very comfy for male organs (three of them), however because its wings don't flex down, it constantly gets in the way of moving thighs. 130 version might be the better though in this regard.*